# TablelayoutPanel isn't resizing for the contents in rows after the first two rows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I think it's some type of but I am having a very weird problem

So I have a `TableLayoutPanel` initially with 2 rows and 2 columns. I add a `Label` on the left column and `Textbox`es on the right. So far so good.

Then I set the `TableLayoutPanel`'s `Autosize` property to `true` and set its `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`.

Now I insert new rows. However whenever I try to insert a control like `Label` or `TextBox` the tablelayout doesn't expand instead it goes on something like this

[image: Orignal Image]

and when I run the program and type it looks something like this

[image: Next Image]

Now I am pretty sure this is some sort of bug, if it isn't help is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost surely didn't configure the control correctly.  Looks like that third row is set to SizeType = Absolute, the default setting you get when you add a row.  Which, when set too small, will clip the content.

Click the little triangle at the top right of the control and select "Edit Rows and Columns". Select Show = Rows and change the SizeType of all rows to AutoSize.

Comment: Oh good anyway i can make this is the default configuration for adding new rows, so after adding new row i don't have to change it every time.

Comment: There is no config for that designer.  Nor would you want that feature, pretty hard to drop a control on an empty row that's 0 pixels tall.

Answer (score -1):

I am having a similar issue, even when the sizetype for all rows is `Autosize`.
[image]

I resolved the issue by making the `Anchor` for the `TableLayoutPanel` as `Top, Button`, it's working fine.

But, in the designer I can see the `TableLayoutPanel` overlapping the next frame.

Comment: Can someone help me too?